# Changing qq(Argument "%s" isn't numeric in sort at %s line %d." message)

Tags: perl, warnings

How can I change the Perl warning message that the sort function throws when it finds a non-numeric value during a numeric sort?

```
$ cat t.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @ulist = qw(1 2 5x 4 3);
my @slist = sort { $a <=> $b } @ulist;

$ t.pl
Argument "5x" isn't numeric in sort at ./t.pl line 5.
```

I'd like to be able to make the code print this instead:

```
$ t.pl
./t.pl: Argument "5x" isn't numeric in sort.
```

Comment: Why would you want it to print less information?

Comment: Vlad H: ...To match the error message standard for the remainder of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without getting into whether this is a good idea or not, you can use a `__WARN__` signal handler to chop off the stack trace info.

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { 
    my $msg = pop(@_); 
    $msg =~ s/ at \S+ line \d+//;
    print STDERR @_, $msg
};
my @slist = sort { $a <=> $b } @ulist;
```

Comment: Easier than that would be to append a newline to the message, which prevents line information from being added.

Comment: But the warning message is from Perl, not from a user message. The line number info is already a part of the message by the time it gets to `$SIG{__WARN__}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could countermand the warning pragma:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @ulist = qw(1 2 5x 4 3);
my @slist;
{
  no warnings 'numeric';
  @slist = sort { $a <=> $b } @ulist;
}
```

Pragmas are lexically scoped, including inversions of them. So the `no warnings` statement will last until the end of its enclosing block. (And as was pointed out in the comments, you can disable just the relevant warning too!)

Comment: Or even better, you can turn off just the warning you don't want with (in this case): no warnings "numeric";

Comment: Good call. I'd forgotten about the fact that there were specific warnings.

Comment: You can always put it in the sort block itself: `@slist = sort { no warnings "numeric"; $a <=> $b } @ulist;`.

Comment: Got it; but mob nailed the issue, because I don't want to *suppress* the warnings. I want the warning text to comply with the format defined for our products.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should make sure the arguments are numeric before using the <=> operator, which requires numbers.  If you just want to sort anything, you can use the cmp operator.

Comment: Considered that, but for this app, it's perfect to warn as non-numeric values go by and just let sort() behave naturally, which does produce the correct answer in the overwhelming majority of cases.